# Angularjs filter basics

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Very simple question about custom filter. What i don't get is how the products objects are passed to the filter as `items` or how the filter has access to them?

I guess it has to do with the the `<li ng-repeat="product in products | priceFilter:prices>` but a clear explanation would help as google and reading the angularjs docs hasn't helped much so far.

**js file**

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);

myAppModule.filter('priceFilter', function() {
   return function( items, prices) {
    console.log(items);
    var filtered = []
    // Are all the brands active?
    var allInActive = true;
    for(var price in prices){
      if(prices[price].active){
        allInActive = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(allInActive){
      return items;
    }

    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {

      if(item.price_desc != null){

        if(prices[item.price_desc].active){
          filtered.push(item);
        }        
      }
    });

    return filtered;
  };
});

function ProductsController($scope, $filter) {

  $scope.products = productsData;
}
```

**html**

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products | priceFilter:prices" ></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of the `|` operator in Angular in a similar way as in a bash command.  The `|` is *piping* the result of the left-hand expression (in your case `products` to the right-hand side.  Underneath, this is just a nice and convenient way to call a filter from the view template.

When `|` is used, the collection that is on the left-hand side is sent in the a filter function to *complete* the filter.  A filter always requires at least on parameter (the array that is being filtered).  So, Angular is *safe* to make the assumption that there will always be *something* to filter on the left-hand side.

It is slightly easier to see the underlying function call with the `$filter(name)` syntax:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

The `'filter'` above is the name of the filter, and then, the first parameter `array` is the *source* array to apply the `expression` to.

So, the `|` is just a convenient way to use `$filter` without having to explicitly pass the `array` parameter.

[Link to documentation here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: so the source array `products` remains intact and isn't affected by calling `product in products`?

Comment: Yes, however, you can add another pipe and another filter to the right - hand side. Each filter will then be applied from left to right.